# Pointer events or mouse over trough image mask in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mouseevent, pointer-events

I have a container with an image mask and children with onMouseOver events and hover styles

Any pointer events do not work through the mask, and they do work outside the mask, where the content is not visible. I want the other way around, to get the pointer events in the visible section, and ignore them in the invisible non-masked part.

I tried setting pointer-events: none on the container and pointer-events: auto on the child but this does not work.

Here is my stylus file

```
.container {    
  width 100%
  position absolute
  height 100%    
  pointer-events none    
  mask-image: url('../../images/mask.svg')
  mask-size 600px auto    
  mask-repeat: no-repeat
  .turns {
    position absolute
    pointer-events auto
    &:hover{
       ...
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there any way around this? I don't mind if I have to use javascript, or apply the mask differently.

Thank you

Edit:

Now after this tutorial https://codepen.io/machal/pen/jrPpdO, I am trying this:

```
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
      <clipPath id="clip-path">
        <path d="M22.154,108.389 L258.274,13.5 L449.156,151.421 L487.774,429.469 L211.933,472.5 L30.981,366.577 L22.154,108.389 z"/>
      </clipPath>
      <div
        style={{
            width: `600px`,
            height: `600px`,
            background: `blue`,          
          }}
        clip-path="url(#clip-path)"
      />
</svg>
```

But the div is not even visible.

Comment: Did you try playing around with the z-indexes ?

Comment: @Winston I did not, but I don't know if it will make a difference since both divs they are nested within each other